# Is there any way to create new url route?

Tags: magento-1.9

I wanna create a page with custom url route. Do you have some references for me? I really frustated because stuck in two days.

I wanna create page like this:

www.myWeb.id/custom-route/

Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can create new router from your module's **config.xml**

So create in your Films folder etc/, with in config.xml. config.xml contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
 <modules>
    <Pfay_Films>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Pfay_Films>
 </modules>
 <frontend>
   <routers>
      <routeurfrontend>
          <use>standard</use>
          <args>
             <module>Pfay_Films</module>
             <frontName>films</frontName>
          </args>
       </routeurfrontend>
   </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

You can learn from below links

https://www.pierrefay.com/en/magento-training/create-a-controller-tutorial.html
http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/magento-hello-world-module-extension/

and for more information on router

https://www.atwix.com/magento/create-custom-router/

http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-router-in-magento/

Comment: How can i write PHP script on that page? eg: www.myWeb.id/custom-route/ how to to write php script in custom-route?

Comment: You need to create controller file check here you to create router and controller

https://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/magento-hello-world-module-extension/